How can I translate strings from another language to english and vice versa in Twig templates?
I am working on a page in drupal 10.3.5 and I have certain texts in a twig template that I need to translate from spanish to english with the module "interface translation", however, when adding the parameter "t" and going to the translation Interface, the text appears to translate from english to spanish, and i need to have it translated from spanish (text language) to english
{{ 'Ver más'|t }}

When I go to the interface translation section: /admin/config/regional/translateand i translate it:

The results is:
Page in english:
Ver más

Page in spanish:
More

and the desired result is as follows:
Page in english:
More

Page in spanish:
Ver más

How can I achieve this result from the interface and without changing the texts on the Twig?

You can't. You must use english in Twig and then translate to other languages. In code, english is always the base language.

You need to search for all the strings and put them in English to translate them into any other language using the translation interface.

In Drupal, all interface text must use English as its default language, as in previous versions of Drupal. Also, as in previous versions of Drupal, the project uses automatic mechanisms to extract translatable text strings from the code base, so that translation teams can use Drupal translations to translate the text of Drupal Core and contributed projects.

Read more in the Translation API overview page
